# Detecting complicated motions on the basis of sensory data

Tags: android, algorithm, sensors, detection, sensormanager

I am pretty new in android sensory stuff such as accelerometer, gravity or gyroscope sensors and I hope that maybe here is someone who wants to/can help.

Lets say I am trying to detect if a user is doing a throwing motion with his/her phone. In android there is a sensormanager,  where you can register a listener for sensor data changes and you get like tons of sensory data each second.

Now I am looking for an efficient and precise algorithm to best detect that throwing motion. What I am doing right now is: each time I get sensory data changes I check on my conditions e.g. is the phone moving with certain speed into the positive x direction or on which axis the gravity force is located (to find out how the phone is rotated).

If the sensory data meets all conditions I store the value in a livedata object with a timestamp to make sure that all parts of the motion are in a certain amount of time (800 millisec).

Is it a good solution? Do you have any other suggestions? On what to do different/better? Thanks to you in advance.

Comment: before going to  `efficient and precise algorithm `.. what is ur current code/algo/math that defines ur `detect that throwing motion` ? mind sharing the research/tested [details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ?

Comment: Right now I am using the accelerometer and its sensor data to determine if the user moves the phone from in front of the face position to the right side. If the phone moves faster than a specified value, I store the value with a timestamp.

And then I use gravity sensordata to determine if the phone moves from portrait mode the right landscape mode and then to left landscape mode. If this is true and this happens in under 500 millisec. I also store this value with a timestamp. 

If the time difference between the 2 stored values is under 1 sec then I declare this motion as detected.

Comment: The problem is that this approach is only for the right side(for people doing the motion with the right hand). What happens if a user is left handed and this motion with the left hand? 
I also hope that I could explain what I do.

Comment: a vector translation should do. `(original limit > new limit)` ---> `y > y | z > z | x  > -x`

Comment: What do you mean by that? And how is this better than what I am doing? Could you please further elaborate on that?

Comment: Can u share the values for the limit defined in ` is the phone moving with certain speed into the positive x direction ` for all 3 axis..?

Comment: if the original limit for `[x,y,z]` is `[20,20,20]`, the new limit (to try) should be `[-20,20,20]`